# Using SQL CASE statement but returning same column values

Tags: sql, case

I'm a novice in SQL & have the following issue:

I have the following column in a table called performances:

```
numbers
-------
13.80
4.9
32.1
0.00
12
0.00
```

I would like to select this table, but where 0.00, I want to return -.  So after the select it should be:

```
numbers
-------
13.80
4.9
32.1
-
12
-
```

I've tried using a case as follows:

```
select
    numbers, 
    case numbers
        when 0.00 then '-' 
    end as numbers
from 
    Performance
```

I know this incorrect & another spanner in the works is that the numbers column datatype is `decimal(18, 2)`

Can someone please assist me with this select? Like I mentioned, I'm still new to SQL, but I'm thinking `CASE` is not the right option for this.

THANK YOU

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This smells like you're asking for a solution to the wrong problem. Have you considered using NULL values instead of 0.00, if 0.00 means there are no measurements?

Do you want '-' when presenting the data? If so, you should not do that in your database layer, but in your application layer.

Comment: YES - It is only for presenting the data, no change is made to the DB

Comment: So the proper way to do it would be to check the value in your program, and if it is equal to 0.0 print '-' instead. Consider also using NULL instead of 0.0 if there's no measurement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast your numbers to a `varchar(19)` (18 + decimal separator).

```
select case numbers 
         when 0 
         then '-' 
         else cast(numbers as varchar(19)) 
       end as numbers
```